# Looping through dictionary to create multiple lists/strings

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, bioinformatics

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
a = {
    (1, 'M'): 0.106997,
    (2, 'R'): 0.167087,
    (3, 'H'): 0.25406,
    (4, 'I'): 0.332115,
    (5, 'I'): 0.324872,
    (6, 'C'): 0.328603,
    ...
}
```

The keys represent the position in a protein sequence as well as the amino acid at that position. The value is some number between 0 and 1. I'm trying to write some code that will string together **consecutive** amino acids if the value is greater than or equal to 0.4. When it reaches an amino acid that has a value less than 0.4 it needs to continue reading through the dictionary until it reaches another set of consecutive amino acids with values greater/equal to 0.4. Ideally this will create multiple independent strings of amino acids.

Here is my code

```
import re
import requests
URL = 'https://iupred2a.elte.hu/iupred2a/long/P03255.json'
response = requests.get(URL)
out = response.json()

seq = out['sequence']
score = out['iupred2']

seq_num = enumerate(seq, start=1)

merge = dict(zip(seq_num, score))

region = ''

for key, value in merge.items():
    if value >= 0.40:
        region += key[1]

print(region)
```

With this all amino acids with a value over 0.4 are concatenated. I need to modify this so that only consecutive amino acids with values over 0.4 are concatenated.

Comment: This assumes dictionaries have order .. they are insert ordered but ... still.

Comment: What is your problem, where is your [mre] and whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a list of regions where a region is a string of amino acids meeting your consecutive value criteria.  If so, then this may do the trick for  you:

```
region_list = []
region = ""
for key, value in merge.items():
    if value >= 0.40:
        region += key[1]
    elif region:
        region_list.append(region)
        region = ""
if region:
    region_list.append(region)
    
for region in region_list:
    print(region)
```

```
A
DQLIEEVLADNLPPPSHFEPPTLHELYDLDVTAPEDPNEEAVSQIFPDS
GIDLLTFPPAPGSPEPPHLSRQPEQPEQRALGPVSMPNLVPEVIDLTCHEAGFPPSDDEDEEGEEFVLDYVE
CRSCHYH
SPVSEPEPEPEPEPEPARPTRRPKMAPAILRRPTSPVSRECNSSTDSCDSGPSNTPPEIHPVVP
PV
V
G
RQAVECIEDLLNEPGQPLDLSCKRPRP
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66168552/8056572) is assuming that the dictionary `merge` is ordered (i.e. when you iterate over, you will the key -> value ordered by the sequence index) which is not always the case.

In general when you want to filter a list (e.g. `seq`) by another list (e.g. `score`) you should use the `zip` built-in function of Python which allows to loop on several lists at the same time. The rest of the algorithm is similar:

```py
import re
import requests
URL = 'https://iupred2a.elte.hu/iupred2a/long/P03255.json'
response = requests.get(URL)
out = response.json()

seq = out['sequence']
score = out['iupred2']

region_list = []
region = ""
for aa, s in zip(seq, score):
    if s >= 0.40:
        region += aa
    elif region:
        region_list.append(region)
        region = ""
if region:
    region_list.append(region)
    
for region in region_list:
    print(region)
```

And it gives you the expected output:

```
AA
DQLIEEVLADNLPPPSHFEPPTLHELYDLDVTAPEDPNEEAVSQIFPDS
GIDLLTFPPAPGSPEPPHLSRQPEQPEQRALGPVSMPNLVPEVIDLTCHEAGFPPSDDEDEEGEEFVLDYVE
CRSCHYH
SPVSEPEPEPEPEPEPARPTRRPKMAPAILRRPTSPVSRECNSSTDSCDSGPSNTPPEIHPVVP
PV
V
G
RQAVECIEDLLNEPGQPLDLSCKRPRP
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't worrying about the order because recent versions of python preserve order by default now. Or at least that was my understanding.  I am new to this but I understand that using your method would work on older versions of python and are more clear. I assume it's better not to rely on this feature of python.

Comment: Yes exactly! The order of insertion in a dictionary is kept with the latest python versions but it can be dangerous to rely on this kind of hidden feature. Anyway, both solutions are working, hope it helped you!